# How to enlarge multiple pictures using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

[click picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JgXE.png) [outcome that I want with multiple pictures though](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS0ta.png)

I've been tasked with fixing this problem out and I just can't grasp it. I want to enlarge multiple pictures using JavaScript. I can get one picture to enlarge but when I try for other images I get no response.

I tried making img id a class and I tried to make multiple different id's but nothing I do works so here I am.

I'm using code from W3school

```js
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
    
    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
    var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
    img.onclick = function(){
      modal.style.display = "block";
      modalImg.src = this.src;
      captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    }
    
    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    
    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() { 
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
```

```css
    
    img id="myImg"

    #myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}
    
    /* The Modal (background) */
    .modal {
      display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  

    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
      z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */

  

    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%; /* Full width */
      height: 100%; /* Full height */
      overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
      background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
    }
    
    /* Modal Content (image) */
    .modal-content {
      margin: auto;
      display: block;
      width: 80%;
      max-width: 700px;
    }
    
    /* Caption of Modal Image */
    #caption {
      margin: auto;
      display: block;
      width: 80%;
      max-width: 700px;
      text-align: center;
      color: #ccc;
      padding: 10px 0;
      height: 150px;
    }
    
    /* Add Animation */
    .modal-content, #caption {  
      -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
      animation-name: zoom;
      animation-duration: 0.6s;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes zoom {
      from {-webkit-transform: scale(0)} 
      to {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
    }
    
    @keyframes zoom {
      from {transform: scale(0.1)} 
      to {transform: scale(1)}
    }
    
    /* The Close Button */
    .close {
      position: absolute;
      top: 15px;
      right: 35px;
      color: #f1f1f1;
      font-size: 40px;
      font-weight: bold;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .close:hover,
    .close:focus {
      color: #bbb;
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    /* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
      .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <h2>Image Modal</h2>
    <p>In this example, we use CSS to create a modal (dialog box) that is hidden by default.</p>
    <p>We use JavaScript to trigger the modal and to display the current image inside the modal when it is clicked on. Also note that we use the value from the image's "alt" attribute as an image caption text inside the modal.</p>
    <p>Don't worry if you do not understand the code right away. When you are done with CSS, go to our JavaScript Tutorial to learn more.</p>
    
    <img id="myImg" src="http://orig03.deviantart.net/558e/f/2013/324/2/7/cute_anime_cat_girl_by_ssyomako-d6uyf48.jpg" alt="Pink hair kitty cat ^-^" width="300" height="200">
    
    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
      <div id="caption"></div>
    </div>
    
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working solution using onclick.
you have to pass image id dynamically in to script.
Hope this will help your study.

```js
 function openModal(id) {
   // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
    
    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
    var img = document.getElementById(id);
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

      modal.style.display = "block";
      modalImg.src = img.src;
      captionText.innerHTML = img.alt;
          // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    
    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() { 
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }

}
```

```css
    img:hover {opacity: 0.7;}
    
    /* The Modal (background) */
    .modal {
      display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  

    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
      z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */

  

    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%; /* Full width */
      height: 100%; /* Full height */
      overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
      background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
    }
    
    /* Modal Content (image) */
    .modal-content {
      margin: auto;
      display: block;
      width: 80%;
      max-width: 700px;
    }
    
    /* Caption of Modal Image */
    #caption {
      margin: auto;
      display: block;
      width: 80%;
      max-width: 700px;
      text-align: center;
      color: #ccc;
      padding: 10px 0;
      height: 150px;
    }
    
    /* Add Animation */
    .modal-content, #caption {  
      -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
      animation-name: zoom;
      animation-duration: 0.6s;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes zoom {
      from {-webkit-transform: scale(0)} 
      to {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
    }
    
    @keyframes zoom {
      from {transform: scale(0.1)} 
      to {transform: scale(1)}
    }
    
    /* The Close Button */
    .close {
      position: absolute;
      top: 15px;
      right: 35px;
      color: #f1f1f1;
      font-size: 40px;
      font-weight: bold;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .close:hover,
    .close:focus {
      color: #bbb;
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    /* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
      .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <h2>Image Modal</h2>
    <p>In this example, we use CSS to create a modal (dialog box) that is hidden by default.</p>
    <p>We use JavaScript to trigger the modal and to display the current image inside the modal when it is clicked on. Also note that we use the value from the image's "alt" attribute as an image caption text inside the modal.</p>
    <p>Don't worry if you do not understand the code right away. When you are done with CSS, go to our JavaScript Tutorial to learn more.</p>
    
    <img id="myImg1" src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.sm.jpg" alt="Pink hair kitty cat ^-^" width="300" height="200" onclick="openModal(this.id)">
        <img id="myImg2" src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/2.jpg" alt="Black hair kitty cat ^-^" width="300" height="200" onclick="openModal(this.id)">
    
    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
      <div id="caption"></div>
    </div>
    
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of onclick event on image click.
So i have added a onclick= somefunct(this) on each images.

Also make sure you include your script just above the  closing body tag

i.e.

```
</body>
```

Now you can observe that the el that is passed as argument in somefunct is the element itself.

SO i have also modified your

```
var img = document.getElementById('myImg')
```

to

```
var img = el;
```

Also modified:

```
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
```

to

```
     modalImg.src = el.src;
     captionText.innerHTML = el.alt;
```

Here is the complete working one:

```
    </head>
    <body>

    <h2>Image Modal</h2>
    <p>In this example, we use CSS to create a modal (dialog box) that is hidden by default.</p>
    <p>We use JavaScript to trigger the modal and to display the current image inside the modal when it is clicked on. Also note that we use the value from the image's "alt" attribute as an image caption text inside the modal.</p>
    <p>Don't worry if you do not understand the code right away. When you are done with CSS, go to our JavaScript Tutorial to learn more.</p>

    <img id="myImg" src="http://orig03.deviantart.net/558e/f/2013/324/2/7/cute_anime_cat_girl_by_ssyomako-d6uyf48.jpg" alt="Pink hair kitty cat ^-^" width="300" height="200" onclick="somefunct(this)">

    <img id="myImg2" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/875749462957670400/T0lwiBK8_400x400.jpg" width="300" height="200"  onclick=somefunct(this)>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
      <div id="caption"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
    // Get the modal
    function somefunct (el) {
            var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
        console.log(el);
    var img = el;
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
    modal.style.display = "block";
      modalImg.src = el.src;
      captionText.innerHTML = el.alt;
    /* img.onclick = function(){

    }
     */
    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() { 
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
    </script>

    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Um.... I'm so lost what exactly did you do? I'm studying it and yeah for example where is img2 being "set" I assume it's an id

Comment: I have mentioned the modifications that i have made in your code. On the mentioned modifications are to be paid attention to. If any other modifications are there , you can ignore that

Comment: Yeah, that way works but things not what I'm going. Sorry, that's my fault I forgot to add pictures.